# last object is getting duplicated inside entire arraylist

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[line 27 is executed before 22 please let me know where i am going wrong,Thanks in advance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhLWY.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGz3S.jpg)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, copy and paste your code here.

Comment: Please post all relevant information here.

Comment: please if anyone knows where i am going wrong let me know and my assumption is the object where the duplicate occurs.

Comment: @AravindhanSaravanan, Please update your query with your code and proper description.